# Composer dies when trying to install any package

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a Laravel application which I noticed that I am no longer able to install any package. As an example. I am trying to install kint which I have done so many other time on other projects

Below is an example of the output and I hope this is enough for someone to point me in the right direction. What can I do to resolve this issue?

```
composer require kint-php/kint --dev -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/var/www/my-application): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /root/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /var/www/my-application/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.6.3 (2018-01-31 16:28:17) with PHP 7.4.3 on Linux / 4.15.0-58-generic
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Executing command (/var/www/my-application/nova/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/var/www/my-application/nova/): git rev-list master..develop
Executing command (/var/www/my-application/nova-components/Dark/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019-04.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019-07.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest%241cb0d80d8313b943a23518d09fb5045f87b8cbc543ff991b11683d4b9c385168.json
Writing /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-kint-php$kint.json from cache
Using version ^3.3 for kint-php/kint
./composer.json has been updated
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Executing command (/var/www/my-application): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /root/.config/composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /var/www/my-application/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading ./composer.lock
Loading composer repositories with package information
Executing command (/var/www/my-application/nova/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/var/www/my-application/nova/): git rev-list master..develop
Executing command (/var/www/my-application/nova-components/Dark/): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2017.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2018.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019-04.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019-07.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2019-10.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2020-01.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$http-message.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$log.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-psr$simple-cache.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-algolia$algoliasearch-client-php.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-illuminate$console.json from cache
Reading /root/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-illuminate$contracts.json from cache
Killed
```

Below is an example of my `composer.json`. I am not sure what to do at this point but was thinking of removing packages and trying to do an install.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-imagick": "*",
        "algolia/scout-extended": "^1.9",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "benjaminhirsch/nova-slug-field": "^1.2",
        "bidgarage/dark": "*",
        "butschster/meta-tags": "^1.4",
        "carlson/nova-link-field": "^1.0",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^5.3",
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.5",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "froala/nova-froala-field": "^3.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/cashier": "^10.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/horizon": "^3.3",
        "laravel/nova": "*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.3",
        "laravel/scout": "^8.0",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.3",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.0",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.7",
        "spatie/laravel-cookie-consent": "^2.11",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.6",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^7.27"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "kint-php/kint": "^3.3",
        "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
        "laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./nova"
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./nova-components/Dark"
        }
    ],
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 777 storage",
            "php artisan passport:install",
            "php artisan storage:link"
        ]
    }
}
```